# GCP Endpoints Path Templating mapping issue

Tags: swagger, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi

Got following issue using OpenAPI / Swagger with ESP 1.35.0 on Cloud Run:

```
 /go/{ppage}/subitem:
   get:
     summary: Get a subitem
     operationId: ppage
     parameters:
       - in: path
         name: ppage
         type: string
         required: true
         description: Get/Retrieve a subitem
     x-google-backend:
       address: https://example.com/go
```

Given an operation config above, path gets translated into `https://example.com/go?ppage=m2jobs`, where:

- `{ppage}` path parameter becomes query parameter with key `ppage` in a call to the backend and
- `/subitem` part of the path vanishes in a call to the backend

Is it correct/expected?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, according with the following link, the backend proto translates the path parameter to query parameter and the /path/ vanishes after the first /{path param}/

https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/backend.proto#L35-L91

Your assumptions are correct!

Best